# Using a quartz composer image effect in iOS app

Tags: ios, image-processing, filter, quartz-2d, quartz-composer

This seems like a straightforward question but I cant seem to find a definitive answer...

If I create a Quartz Composer QTZ file that applies some image library effects (let's say "bloom" and "color invert" as examples) how would I go about importing that QTZ effect into an iOS app as an image filter? Or is there another, better way to share how QTZ creates an image effect with an xcode ios developer?

To be fully clear ultimately I would like to use a QTZ file that would correspond to a filter in the final app. The end user could tap the filter button and the QTZ filter would run on the image they've chosen to manipulate. Like the way you would do with instagram, flickr, etc.

Comment: ok, so this has been asked before. Can anyone point me to the duplicate question?

Answer (score 0):

iOS doesn't have support for Quartz Composer. Use a CIFilter.

Comment: Is there a way for me to create the effect I want in quartz composer and then be able to describe how to duplicate it in CIFilter or is that wishful thinking?

Comment: What do you mean "is there a way"? There's words, I suppose. Not sure what you're after.